# Adding WMS Layer Leaflet Trouble

Tags: leaflet, wms

**The Problem:**

I'm pretty new to leaflet and I'm trying to add a outline of the states over my OSM layer via WMS. I've found several tutorials online, some directly from the leaflet website but haven't had any success.

*My code:*

```
var map;
var feature;

function load_map() {
    map = new L.Map('map', {zoomControl: true});

    var osmUrl = 'http://<my_server>/osm_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            osmAttribution = 'Map data &copy; 2012 <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttribution});

    map.setView(new L.LatLng(0, 0), 3).addLayer(osm);


    var states = L.tileLayer.wms('http://<my_server>:8080/geoserver/States/wms', {
    format: 'img/png',
    transparent: true,
    layers: "null"
    });

    states.addTo(map);
}

window.onload = load_map;
```

When I open the console in google chrome there are no reported errors with my java script or connecting to the server. When the map is displayed it has no problem displaying the OSM layer, but the WMS layer is missing.

Comment: Is 'null' the name of a layer in your WMS that you want to display?  I think the layers parameter should be a list of the layers you want to show.

Comment: You were right on that error, I fixed that, unfortunately, I still can't get the layer to display.

Answer (score 5):

Try "image/png" as your media type, per the change to the load_map function below.  img/png is not a valid mime type and may be confusing the WMS.  Assuming the layer name is "state_boundaries", this should work:

```
var states = L.tileLayer.wms('http://<my_server>:8080/geoserver/States/wms',
{
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    layers: "state_boundaries"
});
states.addTo(map);
```

Comment: This statement would be better as a comment unless you include some reference links as to why "image/png" is supported or a working example... one line answers may be correct but can end up not being overly helpful to future readers as they lack context.

Comment: You need at least 50 reputation points to add a comment, except this one, for some reason.

Comment: Yeh, I forget. It's been a long time since I had less than 50 rep.. the restriction is on 'other than yours' so you can add a comment to any of *your* questions or answers. I see that you've expanded this so it's now a valid answer. Keep up the good work and it wont be long before you get 50 rep.